# How to make an average of nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to make an average array of a bigger and dynamic array. Simpler looks like this:

```
const bigArr = [[[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]],[[3,3,3], [4,4,4], [7,7,7]]]
```

in the end, I'm expecting to get:

```
const averageArray = [[2,2,2], [3,3,3], [5,5,5]]
```

I know the best way is to triple loop over this array's, but I couldn't manage to get expected result.

averageArray[0][0] is an average of bigArr[0][0] and bigArr[1][0].

Comment: What does average array mean here?

Comment: averageArray[0][0] is and average of bigArr[0][0] and bigArr[1][0].

Comment: Why does your average array have 3 sub arrays, but your big array only have two sub arrays? Where do the averages of 3 and 5 come from?

Comment: @DariuszSikorra does my answer give the output you expect? Did I interpret your comment correctly "averageArray[0][0] is and average of bigArr[0][0] and bigArr[1][0]" and extend it to the other indexes correctly? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61750703/9792594

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, on empty arrays its works great. But in a review of the problem, I discovered that I asked the question wrong. I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794157/merging-objects-to-obtain-the-average-value-in-arrays

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it (for loops, reduce, etc.) here I show an example with reduce:

```js
const bigArr = [
              [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]],
              [[3,3,3], [4,4,4], [7,7,7]],
              //[[5,5,5], [6,6,6], [11,11,11]]
            ];

const averageArray = bigArr.reduce((aggArr, arr, i) => {
  
  if (i == 0){
    return arr.map( a => a );
  }
  else {
    arr.forEach( (a, j) => {
      a.forEach( (b, k) => {
        aggArr[j][k] = ((aggArr[j][k] * i) + b) / (i + 1)
      })     
    });
  }  
  
  return aggArr;
}, []);

console.log(averageArray);
```

Output:

```js
[[2,2,2], [3,3,3], [5,5,5]]
```

It would also work with a larger input like this:

```js
const bigArr = [
              [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]],
              [[3,3,3], [4,4,4], [7,7,7]],
              [[5,5,5], [6,6,6], [11,11,11]]
            ];
```

We get this output:

```js
[[3,3,3], [4,4,4], [7,7,7]]
```

One final example:

It would also work with a larger input with non identical sub-arrays like this (to illustrate how the averaging is occurring):

```js
const bigArr = [
              [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]],
              [[3,4,7], [3,4,7], [3,4,7]],
              [[5,6,11], [5,6,11], [5,6,11]]
            ];
```

We get this output:

```js
[[3,4,7], [3,4,7], [3,4,7]]
```