# Merging objects to obtain the average value in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, average

I'm trying to obtain an average value for *scores* arrays and leave other values from the first object. I can't manage how to loop through the objects to achieve expected output.

```
const bigArr = [
  {
    bigDummyData: "string0",
    examples: [
      { smallDD: "string00", scores: [1, 1, 5] },
      { smallDD: "string01", scores: [2, 2, 4] },
      { smallDD: "string02", scores: [2, 2, 6] },
    ],
  },
  {
    bigDummyData: "string1",
    examples: [
      { smallDD: "string10", scores: [3, 3, 3] },
      { smallDD: "string11", scores: [2, 2, 2] },
      { smallDD: "string12", scores: [4, 4, 4] },
    ],
  },
]
```

Expected output its:

```
output = {
    bigDummyData: "string0",
    examples: [
      { smallDD: "string00", scores: [2, 2, 4] },
      { smallDD: "string01", scores: [2, 2, 3] },
      { smallDD: "string02", scores: [3, 3, 5] },
    ],
  }
```

As you can see, bigDummyData and each smallDD are left from the first object.

**That's is a simplified example of the problem**, arrays *bigArr* and *examples* are uploaded dynamically, so they are usually much longer.

Comment: How `[2, 2, 4]` is average of `[1, 1, 5]`

Comment: @brk I suppose this is the average of `[1, 1, 5]` and `[3, 3, 3]`

Comment: @brk It's an average of items of 2 arrays:  _scores: [1, 1, 5]_  and _scores: [3, 3, 3]_ gives: _scores: [2, 2, 4]_. More precisely (1+3)/2=2, those are first items in this scores arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help you

```js
const bigArr = [
  {
    bigDummyData: "string0",
    examples: [
      { smallDD: "string00", scores: [1, 1, 5] },
      { smallDD: "string01", scores: [2, 2, 4] },
      { smallDD: "string02", scores: [2, 2, 6] },
    ],
  },
  {
    bigDummyData: "string1",
    examples: [
      { smallDD: "string10", scores: [3, 3, 3] },
      { smallDD: "string11", scores: [2, 2, 2] },
      { smallDD: "string12", scores: [4, 4, 4] },
    ],
  }
]

let firstElement = bigArr[0];
let length = bigArr.length;
bigArr.splice(0,1)

bigArr.forEach(({examples}) => {
  examples.forEach(({scores},i) => {
    firstElement.examples[i].scores = firstElement.examples[i].scores.map( (x,j) => x+scores[j]); 
  })
});

  firstElement.examples.forEach(({scores},i) => {
    firstElement.examples[i].scores = firstElement.examples[i].scores.map( (x) => x/length); 
  });
console.log(firstElement);
```

> **When to use Map**

Creating new array based on doing some operation in existing array.[Official Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> **Splice**

The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements [Official Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Accept this,if it helps you.